# How do I set a default value in rails active record based on two other values in the active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

My users are (booleans) students, tutors, or 'both'. My users are automatically false on all 3 unless specified, but I want the default value of 'both' to be based on a user being both a student and a tutor, therefore if student and tutor are booleans, both = student && tutor. How can I create  a migration to do this?
Migration file that did not work.

```
class ChangeUserBoth < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
change_column :users, :both, :boolean, :default => :student && :tutor
  end
end
```

Comment: This wouldn't be something you'd do in a migration, it'd be something you set in a callback on the model.

But I have to ask: why? If `both` is going to be data that your other two columns can adequately represent, why put yourself in a situation where you *have* to keep data in sync?

Comment: I thought it seemed appropriate, and I do group my users into those 3 categories for what I'm building. However, seeing as how a user can change from a student to both, keeping it in sync would definitely be a problem. I am looking into some documentaton on callbacks.

Comment: To group them, you'd just make scopes for each: only students are `where(student: true, tutor: false)`, only tutors are `where(student: false, tutor: true)`, and both are `where(student: true, tutor: true)`. Adding a third column is wasteful and adds unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a conditional method in while writing your migration code, but you can achieve the desired result through the following way:

```
# In your model code    
before_save :set_both_based_on_student_and_tutor

private
def set_both_based_on_student_and_tutor
  # Ternary way saves your form 'both' being 'nil'. It would always 
  # either be true or false
  self.both = (self.student && self.tutor) ? true : false
end
```

Comment: `after_initialize` callback maybe?

Comment: could be. It happens before every save. And you only need to write in defaults, only once.